# Read file inside ZIP subdirectory with PHP

Tags: php, zip, readfile, php-ziparchive

I want to read a file inside two zip folders...

My tree:
main_zip_folder
 -second_zip_folder
  --file_to_read.xml

It's simple to enter in the first_zip_folder and list all the files persent in this folder. I'm using this example:

```
//create a ZipArchive instance
$zip = new ZipArchive;
//open the archive
if ($zip->open('data/main_zip_folder.zip') === TRUE) {
    //iterate the archive files array and display the filename or each one
    for ($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        echo 'Filename: ' . $zip->getNameIndex($i) . '<br />';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Failed to open the archive!';
}
```

My problem is how to enter in the second_zip_folder to list the files present on it, and open the file_to_read.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I hope it can be help you, This code below help you for reading to zip files or more

```
<?php
$za = new ZipArchive();
$files = array('zip1.zip', 'zip2.zip');

//$za->open('zip1.zip', 'zip2.zip');

foreach ($files as $fil){
    $za->open($fil);
    for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
        $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
        print_r( basename( $stat['name'] ) . PHP_EOL . '<br>');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What I want is to read a file wich is inside a zip folder wich is inside a zip folder.